# how to return result of repr(str) back to str?

Tags: python, utf-8

```
r = 'ыыы'
a = repr(r)
print a
"'\\xd1\\x8b\\xd1\\x8b\\xd1\\x8b'"

a == r
False
```

How to get rid of double slashes? Should I decode or encode it somehow? I want make r back again from a

Answer (score 0):

I think [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) will do what you need:

```
from ast import literal_eval
r = 'ыыы'
a = repr(r)
print(a)
print(literal_eval(a) == r)
```